# Convert a Byte Array from \xff to x0FF

Tags: python, python-3.x, sensors

I'm writing a code in Python 3 to read data from a ECG Sensor. The final code must write to a file the packets received from the sensor.
This is the code that I have actually:

```
import serial


if __name__ == '__main__':
    buffer = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    f = open('dumpECG', 'w')
    print("Hi")
    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 115200)
    while 1 == 1:
        while ser.inWaiting() > 6:
            buf = ser.read()
            if buf > b'\xf7':

                if buf == b'\xfd':
                    1 == 1
                else:
                    buffer[0] = buf
                    if ser.isOpen():
                        buffer[1] = ser.read()
                    if buffer[0] == b'\xf8':
                        temp = (ord(buffer[1]) >> 4) + 2
                        if temp < 11:
                            for i in range(2, int(temp), 1):
                                if ser.isOpen():
                                    buffer[i] = ser.read()
                            print(buffer)
                            data = ''.join(str(e) for e in buffer)
                            data = map(hex, map(ord, data))
                            f.write(''.join(data))
                            f.write("\n")
                    elif buffer[0] == b'\xfe':
                        temp = (ord(buffer[1]) >> 4) + 2
                        if temp < 8:
                            for i in range(2, int(temp), 1):
                                if ser.isOpen():
                                    buffer[i] = ser.read()
                            print(buffer)
                            f.write(''.join(str(e) for e in buffer))
                            f.write("\n")
                    elif buffer[0] == b'\xf9' or buffer[0] == b'\xfa':
                        if ser.isOpen():
                            buffer[2] = ser.read()
                        print(buffer)
                        f.write(''.join(str(e) for e in buffer))
                        f.write("\n")
                    elif buffer[0] == b'\xfc':
                        for i in range(2, int(6), 1):
                            if ser.isOpen():
                                buffer[i] = ser.read()
                        f.write(''.join(str(e) for e in buffer))
                        f.write("\n")
```

As example data, when reaching the first print(buffer) buffer contains: "[b'\xf8', b'8', b'\x80', b'\x80', b'\x80', 0]" and I must write to file "0xF8, 0x38, 0x80, 0x80, 0x80, 0"
I've tried to do that

```
data = ''.join(str(e) for e in buffer)
data = map(hex, map(ord, data))
```

But he converts all characters, instead of values.

Comment: Are you sure you want to map `b'8'` into `'0x08'`, not `'0x38'`?

Comment: Sorry, typing error ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have this:

```
"[b'\xf8', b'8', b'\x80', b'\x80', b'\x80', 0]"
```

And you want this:

```
"0xF8, 0x38, 0x80, 0x80, 0x80, 0"
```

(I'm going to assume you actually want `0x38`, not `0x08`, because `b'8'` is `b'\x38'`, not `b'\x08'`. If I'm wrong, you'll need to explain your rule…)

---

The first thing to notice is that this is clearly output generated by Python's `repr`, because there's nothing else common that's going to give you those `b`-prefixed strings. If at all possible, it would probably be much better to change whatever code generates these strings so that it just passes the list (if within Python) or uses some standardized, safe, robust interchange format like JSON instead of just printing out the `repr`. But if you can't change that, then the way to reverse it is `ast.literal_eval`:

```
>>> ast.literal_eval(buffer)
[b'\xf8', b'8', b'\x80', b'\x80', b'\x80', 0]
```

---

Next, some of these values are single-byte `bytes` objects and some are numbers. It looks like you want to leave the numbers alone, but convert the bytes into hex numbers. So, we need to do different things for each type.

What do we do for each type? Well, for `bytes` we have to call `ord` (or just use `[0]`), then `hex`, as you were trying to do. But for `int` we have to just call `str`. So:

```
>>> [hex(ord(b)) if isinstance(b, bytes) else str(b) 
...  for b in ast.literal_eval(buffer)]
['0XF8', '0X38', '0X80', '0X80', '0X80', '0']
```

And now we just join them up:

```
>>> ', '.join(hex(ord(b)) if isinstance(b, bytes) else str(b) 
...           for b in ast.literal_eval(buffer))
'0xf8, 0x38, 0x80, 0x80, 0x80, 0'
```

If you really need the alphabetic hex digits to be capitalized, `hex` can't do that, so:

```
>>> ', '.join('0x{:2X}'.format(ord(b)) if isinstance(b, bytes) else str(b) 
...           for b in ast.literal_eval(buffer))
'0xF8, 0x38, 0x80, 0x80, 0x80, 0'
```

Comment: Thank you for the perfect explanation! Im trying to use it but it raises me that error ValueError: malformed node or string: [b'\xf8', b'8', b'\x80', b'\x80', b'\x80', 0] in line 28 (ast.literal_eval(buffer))

Comment: @ChristianGil: If you actually have the string `"[b'\xf8', b'8', b'\x80', b'\x80', b'\x80', 0]"` (as you would if, e.g., you wrote `buffer = r"[b'\xf8', b'8', b'\x80', b'\x80', b'\x80', 0]"), you don't get that error. If that's not what you have, then I need to know what you actually have or how can I guess how to parse it?

Comment: Its fine, I've just removed ast and worked as expected. Thanks!

Comment: @ChristianGil: OK, so you didn't have a string representing a list, you just had a list. That's easier, and better. :)

Comment: @ChristianGil: Now that I look at the code you're using to build this up… it looks like the only reason you have those numbers in there is that you start with a list of `0`s, instead of a list of `b'\x00'`. Can you change that? If so, you can obviously simplify the code a bit. Or, even more simply, use a `bytearray(6)` instead of the list `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`.